# value of Points modification

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two points top_left and bottom_right . To increase the area covered by the rectangle drawn from these points, I add/subtract sub values from them.

```
Point  top_left     -= Point( WIDTH_ADD,  HEIGHT_ADD);
Point  bottom_right += Point(WIDTH_ADD , HEIGHT_ADD );
```

Now I need to check whether they surpass the boundary of current frame (captured from camera).
If they do, I need to check and modify their values.

```
if ( top_left.x < 0 )           top_left.x = 0;
if (  bottom_right.x > frame.cols ) bottom_right.x = frame.cols; 
if ( top_left.y < 0 )               top_left.y = 0;
if( bottom_right.y >  frame.rows )      bottom_right.y = frame.rows;
```

Is there any fancy way of doing this in opencv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any, but even if there were, **your code would probably be faster** since you're skipping at least a function call to OpenCV.